# Laravel 5+. Связи между тремя таблицами

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel5

Добрый день, имеется 3 модели:

```
// Пользователь
class User extends Authenticatable
{  
    public function pollsProcesses(){
        return $this->hasMany('PollProcess');
    }
}

// Опрос
class Poll extends Model
{
    public function processes(){
        return $this->hasMany('PollProcess');
    }
}

// Процесс проходения опроса
class PollProcess extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function poll(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Poll');
    }
}
```

Необходимо получить процесс прохождения, если известен пользователь и опрос. Я делаю это так:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$poll = ...;

$currentProcess = $user->pollsProcesses()->where('poll_id',$poll->id);
```

Есть ли более изящное решение? Похожие ситуации у меня есть и в других таблицах.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно вынести это в объект `User`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{  
    public function pollsProcesses(){
        return $this->hasMany('PollProcess');
    }

    public function currentPollProcess(Poll $poll)
    {
        return $this->pollsProcesses()->where('poll_id',$poll->id)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

И тогда обращаться к текущему процессу:

```
$user->currentPollProcess($poll);
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я думал, что есть какой-то вариант записывать эту строку `$user->pollsProcesses()->where('poll_id',$poll->id)` без where. Хочется узнать, можно ли это сделать

Comment: @FelAA А как узнать без where какой вы запросите?